# How can I determine if a div is scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

How do I determine, without using jQuery or any other JavaScript library, if a div with a vertical scrollbar is scrolled all the way to the bottom?

My question is not how to scroll to the bottom. I know how to do that. I want to determine if the the div is scrolled to the bottom already.

This does not work:

```
if (objDiv.scrollTop == objDiv.scrollHeight)
```

Comment: just guessing here if (objDiv.scrollTop > objDiv.scrollHeight)
And may be need to reduce from scrollHeight the size of the scroll arrow (say 20px)

Comment: some documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

   ...   ...  ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

   ...   ...  ...

http://api.jquery.com/height/

  ...   ...  ...  

http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/

  ...  ...  ...

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're pretty close using `scrollTop == scrollHeight`.

`scrollTop` refers to the top of the scroll position, which will be `scrollHeight - offsetHeight`

Your if statement should look like so (don't forget to use triple equals):

```
if( obj.scrollTop === (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight))
{
}
```

Edit: Corrected my answer, was completely wrong

Comment: That almost works, scrollHeight-offsetHeight isn't exatly the same value as scrollTop, but after trying your code, if I require if that difference is fewer than 5 pixels for it to be the bottom I get the behavior I want.

Comment: this is not exact. obj.borderWidth need to be considered

Comment: i prefer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828275/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-check-if-a-div-is-scrolled-all-the-way-to-the-bottom

Comment: `scrollTop` can be non-integral, so this requires some tolerance (say, `obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight - obj.scrollTop < 1`) to work in all circumstances. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828275/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-check-if-a-div-is-scrolled-all-the-way-to-the-bottom/32283147

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fixed elements on my layout or something else odd I'm doing but the only time this evaluates to true is when I scroll all the way to the top.  This is because `document.body.scrollHeight` equals `document.body.offsetHeight` in my instance (Chrome)

Answer (score 61):

In order to get the correct results when taking into account things such as the possibility of a border, horizontal scrollbar, and/or floating pixel count, you should use...

```
el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop - el.clientHeight < 1
```

**NOTE:** You MUST use clientHeight instead of offsetHeight if you want to get the correct results. offsetHeight will give you correct results only when el doesn't have a border or horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Also the only answer that worked for me. I'm using padding to hide the scrollbar.

Comment: clientHeight worked really nice. using the offsetHeight in the accepted answer gave me a result that wasn't 100% accurate

Comment: elegant, thank you.. you can also use it with Vue in a scroll event `@scroll="scrolling"` then in the methods `scrolling(event) { event.target // as el in the answer }` Good luck

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only answer that worked for me on mobile.

Comment: You can check for this when the user scrolls the div, using the built in property [onscroll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Comment: If you dont want to trigger the event many time(like in my case it was triggering 3-4 times) use 0.1 instead of 1

Answer (score 22):

Little late to this party, but none of the above answers seem to work particularly well when...

- Display scaling is applied to the OS for UHD displays
- Scaling/zoom is applied to the browser

To accommodate for all eventualities, you will need to round up the calculated scroll position:

```
Math.ceil(element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop) === element.clientHeight
```

Comment: This answer is the first one that works properly (I have tested the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5828275/ as well). As others have mentioned, margins, zoom and other factors come into play – and this seems to handle them all.
_Edit:_ Spencer's answer below seems to be basically the same, also correct.

Answer (score 11):

Returns true if an element is at the end of its scroll, false if it isn't.

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

Comment: For me, using Chrome, where the element is document.body, this does not work. `document.body.scrollHeight` and `document.bodyclientHeight` have the same value and so the expression is never true.

Comment: What edit can we do so that we can detect, that scroll is near bottom. For example if scroll is below 75%, consider it near bottom

Comment: This just works, plain and simple. +1 Thanks. For anyone wondering where the `element` came from, you can get it by for example `const element = getElementById("yourElementId")`

Answer (score 3):

```js
function difference(first,sec){
  return Math.abs(first-sec);
}

document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var diff = difference((this.scrollTop+this.clientHeight),(this.scrollHeight));
   
   if(diff < 5) {
      alert('Scroll Ends Here');
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll inside the div element to display the number of pixels the content of div is scrolled horizontally and vertically.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">Scroll inside me!</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

No JQuery or Javascript Library and it works well.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me. Slightly a different approach.

```
if (list.scrollTop + list.clientHeight >= list.scrollHeight - 1) {
    return 'scrollOnTheBottom';
}
```

Comment: Wonderfully works! Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-when-user-scrolls-to-the-bottom-of-a-div/ Worked for me, hope it will work for you too.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $( 
        '.div').offset().top + $('.div'). 
        outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) { 
            alert('You reached the end of the DIV'); 
        } 
});
```

Comment: O.P. specifically asked no JS libraries

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>JQuery | Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div. 
    </title> 
</head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<body style="text-align:center;" id="body"> 
    <h1 style="color:green;">  
            Data Center  
        </h1> 
    <p id="data_center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;"></p> 
    <center> 
        <div class="div" style="width:200px; height:150px; overflow:auto;"> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
            <h1>Hello Friends</h1> 
        </div> 
    </center> 
    <script> 
        $('#data_center').text('Scroll till bottom to get alert!'); 
        jQuery(function($) { 
            $('.div').on('scroll', function() { 
                if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >=  $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {                     
                    alert('End of DIV has reached!'); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

It works for me, i hope, this will also help you. Thanks.

Comment: O.P. specifically asked no JS libraries