# How to check if a DIV is scrolled all the way to the bottom with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with overflow:scroll.

I want to know if it's currently scrolled all the way down. How, using JQuery?

This one doesn't work: [How can I determine if a div is scrolled to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876115/how-can-i-determine-if-a-div-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: found this by searching using google, very interesting http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/

Comment: can you explain what happens where the link you've given doesn't work? maybe add some markup too?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here is the correct solution [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/kqRne/). A brief look at the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').on('scroll', chk_scroll);
});

function chk_scroll(e) {
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
        console.log("bottom");
    }
}
```

See [this](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/) for more info.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I'm working on a solution where the div containing the content is resizable, and I need to recheck the scroll status every time the div is resized, as it does not fire every time. Is there an event for that?

Comment: this is a little buggy when you're dealing with boxes that have padding/margins. Not sure what the issue is really. But it *sometimes* says 'bottom' when I do it.

Comment: I believe the example should use "innerHeight" instead of "outerHeight"  or it will not work with borders > 0px.

Comment: what if i have a ul instead of div? When i tried, i always get 2 px difference. if you have any fix other than subtracting the value please let me know. thanks.

Comment: In Chrome, when the browser is zoomed the pixel numbers can be floating (eg. 33.3334216........). To handle this, you could check for differences less than one pixel, for instance: `if (Math.abs(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() - elem.outerHeight()) < 1)`

Comment: What if it's a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Thank you Pokot0! You just saved me a lot of time, because I used suggested solution, and wondered why alert sometimes didn't trigger.

Comment: You can use this solution for horizontal scrolling, too. `elem[0].scrollWidth - elem.scrollLeft() < elem.outerWidth()`

Answer (score 17):

```
function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return el.scrollHeight - $el.scrollTop() - $el.outerHeight() < 1;
}
```

This is variation of @samccone's answer that incorporates @HenrikChristensen's comment regarding subpixel measurements.

Comment: This is THE only answer which works correctly in Chrome at all times. With other answers it sometimes works in Chrome and sometimes doesn't (Firefox doesn't have this subpixel issue and always works regardless).

Comment: Very nice, this solution aggregates every pieces of advice from the comments above. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in both Chrome and Firefox. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Since it works without jQuery like that :

```
 var isBottom = node.scrollTop + node.offsetHeight === node.scrollHeight;
```

I do :

```
 var node = $('#mydiv')[0]; // gets the html element
 if(node) {
    var isBottom = node.scrollTop + node.offsetHeight === node.scrollHeight;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by

```
(scrollHeight - scrollTop()) == outerHeight()
```

Apply required jQuery syntax, of course...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code:

```
$("#div_Id").scroll(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this);            
    if (elem.scrollTop() > 0 && 
            (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight())) {
        alert("At the bottom");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Since 2012](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766937) Firefox contains the [`scrollTopMax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTopMax) property. If `scrollTop === scrollTopMax` you're at the bottom of the element.

Comment: Interesting, though not supported by any browser (and doesn't seem like it ever will be?)

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery, for onScroll event

```
var scrollDiv = event.srcElement.body
window.innerHeight + scrollDiv.scrollTop == scrollDiv.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `$el.outerHeight()` gives the wrong value (due to the border width), whereas `$el.innerHeight()` gives the correct one, so I use

```
function isAtBottom($el){

    return ($el[0].scrollHeight - $el.scrollTop()) == $el.innerHeight();
}
```