# Scrolling div must be scrolled to bottom before you can check a checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, scroll, onchange

I have a div that contains a disclaimer, I want to make sure someone has scrolled to the bottom of the disclaimer before you can check the checkbox acknowledging you have read the disclaimer. Legal Dept.
Here is a sample markup:

```
<div id="step2Disclaimer" style="height:50px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>                             
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="acknowledge" name="acknowledge" value="true">
<label class="styled" for="acknowledge">I acknowledge</label>
```

I can detect when someone scrolls to the bottom of #acknowledge like this:

```
$('#step2Disclaimer').on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
    alert('end reached');
    }
});
```

What I need to do, and am somehow missing, is on change of "acknowledge" check to see if someone has scrolled. The condition isn't working -> to clarify, if someone checks the checkbox "acknowledge" and HAS NOT scrolled to the bottom of "step2Disclaimer" I need to run a function.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="acknowledge"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && ($('#step2Disclaimer').scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)) {
            alert('checked but not scrolled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can furbish an example of this for you.  It will leverage the jQuery library known as appeared.  I just did a project that ended up being scrapped, but I know more about scrolling than I should.  The gaming company Blizzard typically does this before they allow you to play their games.

Comment: Please do, would be much appreciated. I need to check the scroll position of the div when you check the box.

Comment: No, what Blizzard does, and you should incorporate as best practice, is disable the checkbox **until** the user has scrolled to the bottom of the agreement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you are using `this`, which targets the checkbox, instead of targeting the `div`. Secondly, you need to check if the `scrollTop` plus the `innerHeight` is smaller, and not larger, than the `scrollHeight`. The following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="acknowledge"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && ($('#step2Disclaimer').scrollTop() + $('#step2Disclaimer').innerHeight() < $('#step2Disclaimer')[0].scrollHeight)) {
            alert('checked but not scrolled');
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLsLjsm4/2/)

Comment: Same result I was getting. It doesn't fire the alert if you check the box and don't scroll. However, if you scroll all the way down (as desired) and check the box it fires the alert.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Sorry, forgot to mention the second problem. I edited my answer. It should now work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Jacques. I wasn't targeting the scrolling div correctly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to leverage jQuery.appear nor appear.js as those libraries implicitly deal with the DOM viewport instead of element viewports.  As such, here is the code that will suppress the checkbox until the user has manually scrolled through the contents of the agreement (the very bottom).

> **HTML**

```
<div id="step2Disclaimer">
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>
    <div class='agreement_read'>?</div>
</div>

<input class='unread' type="checkbox" id="acknowledge" name="acknowledge" value="true" disabled>
<label class="styled unread" for="acknowledge">I acknowledge</label>
```

> **CSS**

```
#step2Disclaimer {
    width: 315px;
    border: solid 1px #ACE;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 115px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 3px;
}

.unread {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: dashed 1px red;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #CCC;
}

.fully_read {
    border: solid 1px green;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

> **JavaScript**

```
var master_agreement = document.getElementById('step2Disclaimer');

jQuery(master_agreement).scroll(function(e) {
    if (isScrolledToBottom(master_agreement) && jQuery('.unread').length) {
        jQuery('.unread').removeClass('unread').addClass('fully_read');
        jQuery('#acknowledge').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

//Chris Martin of StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32283147/5076162
function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return el.scrollHeight - $el.scrollTop() - $el.outerHeight() < 1;
}
```

```js
var master_agreement = document.getElementById('step2Disclaimer');

jQuery(master_agreement).scroll(function(e) {
    if (isScrolledToBottom(master_agreement) && jQuery('.unread').length) {
        jQuery('.unread').removeClass('unread').addClass('fully_read');
        jQuery('#acknowledge').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

//Chris Martin of StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32283147/5076162
function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return el.scrollHeight - $el.scrollTop() - $el.outerHeight() < 1;
}
```

```css
#step2Disclaimer {
    width: 315px;
    border: solid 1px #ACE;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 115px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 3px;
}

.unread {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: dashed 1px red;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #CCC;
}

.fully_read {
    border: solid 1px green;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step2Disclaimer">
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>
    <p class="l-twelve l-mb1 t-base t-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate temporibus commodi sapiente culpa sunt iure veniam harum impedit architecto dolorem quam facilis, odio blanditiis beatae similique non voluptatibus at dolorum?</p>
</div>

<input class='unread' type="checkbox" id="acknowledge" name="acknowledge" value="true" disabled>
<label class="styled unread" for="acknowledge">I acknowledge</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the checkbox until the user reaches the end of the page. You can use something like Jquery's hover or mouse over to make the box appear when a user reaches the bottom.

Comment: That would be much easier. However legal dept has laid this behavior out for me.