# how can I test for dynamic elements on the page using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am setting up protractor tests for my angularJs 1.14 app.
We have a video player that displays subtitles. Each subtitle is in a div.  When the player is playing, our code sets the class of the current subtitle to "currentSubtitle"  This way, we can highlight the subtitle.  In addition, we have code that causes the current subtitles's div to be scrolled to.  How can I create a test that tests if the subtitle scroll is working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do 2 things, depending on how fast the automation and the page self is.

1. Have you tried validating which text is visible with `element(by.css('. currentSubtitle').getText()`. `getText()` will give you the visible text, see [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText)
2. Use `browser.driver.executeScript('//some JS code')` to determine if it scrolled, take for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876115/how-can-i-determine-if-a-div-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom). Then you can calculate with JS if the subtitle scroll is working

Hope it helps finding your answer